# ¿Cómo funciona git pull con la opción o bandera --rebase?

Tags: git, git-pull, git-rebase

Se supone que al hacer un `git pull --rebase`, todas mis confirmaciones o `commits` locales, deberían moverse a la punta o final de los `commits` de la rama remota, suponiendo que en la rama local avanzo y se hicieron cambios a un "archivo A" y la rama remota al mismo tiempo avanza e igualmente hace cambios al "archivo A", por ende, todos los `commits` son solo modificaciones al "archivo A", quiero evitar resolver conflictos, por ende aplico el `pull` con la opción `--rebase`; yo al aplicar este comando, esperaba algo así (o al menos algo parecido):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero lo que hace es hacer un `commit` de unión pidiéndome que resuelva el conflicto. Si va a hacer un `commit` de unión mejor utilizo la estrategia por defecto, que es `merge`,por ende, ¿qué hace realmente la opción o bandera `--rebase`? No le hallo una diferencia (al menos en cuanto a resultados).

Comment: Recomendación: cambiá el color de fondo de tu imagen, ya que en el modo oscuro se dificulta leer las letras negras.

Comment: gracias, olvide por completo el modo oscuro c:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tanto si usas `rebase` como si usas `merge` el objetivo en lo que respecta a la carpeta de trabajo es el mismo: dejar una carpeta de trabajo que contenga los cambios que aparecen en **ambas** ramas.

Lo que cambia entre `rebase` y `merge` es la forma en que queda la historia una vez la operación ha finalizado con éxito.

- Cuando usas `merge`, cada rama separada permanece en la historia y se crea un nuevo commit de tipo "merge" (que es un commit que tiene dos padres en vez de uno, que corresponden a las cabezas de las ramas que están siendo mezcladas). Se conservan las fechas en las que en cada rama se hicieron cambios y se puede ver por tanto en qué orden ocurrieron las cosas "realmente"
- Cuando usas `rebase` la historia se ve lineal, los commits que tenías en local se "mueven" (en realidad no, como explicaré enseguida) para ponerse después de los de la rama remota. Se pierde así el orden en que las cosas ocurrieron en realidad, y todo se ve como si los cambios de la rama local hubieran ocurrido después.

  Los commits no se mueven simplemente. Lo que ocurre es que git crea unos commits nuevos, con cambios diferentes, **pero con el resultado final** de que al aplicar esos cambios sobre los que vinieron de la remota el resultado en cuanto a la carpeta de trabajo **es el mismo que si se hubieran mezclado** las ramas.

Así pues, resumiendo y respondiendo ya a tu pregunta.

1. Tu comprensión de lo que hace rebase era básicamente correcta (y muy bonitas figuras, por cierto)
2. Todo habría ocurrido como pensabas, si no hubiera habido conflictos.

Pero...

> Si cada una de las ramas hace modificaciones incompatibles sobre un mismo fichero, se va a producir un conflicto tanto si haces rebase como si haces merge, ya que en lo que respecta al resultado final en la carpeta de trabajo **Git no puede decidir** qué cambios han de prevalecer, si los locales o los remotos.

En definitiva, rebase no es una forma de eliminar conflictos. De hecho no hay forma de eliminar conflictos, salvo evitar modificar el mismo fichero en ramas diferentes. Rebase es una forma de que, una vez resueltos los conflictos, la historia se vea lineal, en vez de bifurcada y unida de nuevo. Es decir, se evitan los commits con dos padres.

Comment: Aahh!!!, claro, lo que pasa es que tenia otro concepto de lo que hacia el rebase, yo pensaba que cuando "movia" los commits, después simplemente los aplicaba con un Fast Forward, lo que hace realmente como tu dices es re escribir o buscando más a profundidad, crea un "parche", claro, los conflictos igual deberán resolverse, ahora me queda más claro, tiene que ver, igualmente, como tu dices, con el historial como tal, si no hay conficltos se puede hacer eso puedo hacer lo que yo quería hacer, pero sino, deben resolverse los conflictos, gracias c:

Answer (score 1):

Lo que hace  `pull --rebase` es hacer un rebase de tu rama sobre su rama `upstream` luego de hacer un fetch. Ahora bien, vamos a lo más técnico, porque creo que tu secuencia de pasos no es la adecuada.

Luego de hacer el `fetch`, comienza el *rebase*. git primero hace un checkout de la revisión en la que está la *otra* rama, es decir la rama *upstream*. Luego calcula cual es esa revisión común que indicas. Entonces git comienza a aplicar (a grandes rasgos, con `git cherry-pick`) las revisiones que están entre la revisión común y la punta de tu rama... como paso final de todo esto, git mueve el apuntador de tu rama original a la revisión final y le hace checkout.

Si al tratar de aplicar *alguna* de las revisiones de tu rama se genera un conflicto, git se va a detener y te va a pedir que le eches una mano para resolverlo (luego de resolverlo, toca hacer `git rebase --continue` y git continuará aplicando las revisiones hasta la última revisión de la rama).

Como comentario final, no entiendo por qué piensas que podrías evitar un conflicto. Si al hacer merge tienes conflictos, al hacer rebase los vas a ver también... incluso podrías ver más conflictos, pero seguro que no vas a ver *menos* conflictos (**podría** pasar *lo contrario*, en todo caso, **si las condiciones son apropiadas** que al hacer rebase veas conflictos, pero al hacer merge no los veas)